# cakephp web.config windows remove index.php from URL

Tags: url, cakephp, web-config

I have uploaded my site on a windows server and i would like to remove the index.php from the URL. I tried to open the web.config but i'm not quite familiar with the syntax. this only happens when i call a link. the homepage doesn't show the index.php.

Comment: Have you read this link yet?http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts

Comment: Yes but it doesn't really show me how to hide the index.php from the URL

Comment: Which index.php are you referring to here?

Comment: [link]www.mysite.com/poker[/link] Error: The requested address '/index.php/poker' was not found on this server.

Comment: Please provide directory structure of your website

Comment: the /poker is a PokerController with and index() method. The structure is /app /Controller /PokerController.php

Comment: and if i click on the menu to go to /index it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Open app/Config/routes.php, and add following to the beginning of the file:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Poker', 'action' => 'index'));
```

By the way, according to CakePHP naming convention. You should have PokersController instead of PokerController.